# How do I make all elements move when I resize the window

Tags: html, css

When I resize the windows from left all the way to the right, #flower-background-1 and #welcome will move to the right; however, the two flower images below (img-1 and img-2) do not move to the right. What do I do so that all they move to the right and are aligned?

```css
#flower-background-1 {
  background-image: url("https://www.fiftyflowers.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/iStock-659171982-1170x449.jpg");
  height: 300px;
  width: 900px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#welcome {
  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 150px;
  background-color: indigo;
}

.image-1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 114px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}

.image-2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<div id="flower-background-1"></div>
<div id="welcome">Welcome to my Flower Shop</div>

<body>
  <img class="image-1" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1204/3320/products/46801850054_ea0cb77ced_o_800x800.jpg?v=1554836834">
  <img class="image-2" src="https://www.1800flowers.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/160080m-274x300.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to is to create a content container surrounding the images and set its width to match your flower background with an auto margin to center it.

```html
<div id="flower-background-1"></div>
<div id="welcome">Welcome to my Flower Shop</div>
<div id="content">
  <img class="image-1" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1204/3320/products/46801850054_ea0cb77ced_o_800x800.jpg?v=1554836834">
  <img class="image-2" src="https://www.1800flowers.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/160080m-274x300.jpg">
</div>
```

```css
#content {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am also trying to add a caption under each one, but when I do that, the whole layout messes up. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Similar to how we created a ```#content``` container you would want to create another container that would contain a single image and caption. I'd encourage reading up on [CSS layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction).

Answer (score 1):

d_ugRiddle's answer is quite good, but i would suggest resetting the margin as well as the postion of the images:

CSS

```
.image-1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
}

.image-2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .image-2, .image-1 {
        margin: 0;
        position: static;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="flower-background-1"></div>
<div id="welcome">Welcome to my Flower Shop</div>
<div id="content">
  <img class="image-1" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1204/3320/products/46801850054_ea0cb77ced_o_800x800.jpg?v=1554836834" />
  <img class="image-2" src="https://www.1800flowers.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/160080m-274x300.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a lot of bugs in your code. Your HTML document is not valid. you have to completely change it. Your CSS is also not written in a good way.
i have corrected all for you. Replace the HTML & CSS code with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="flower-background-1"></div>
    <p id="welcome">Welcome to my Flower Shop</p>
    <div class="img-container">
      <img
        class="image-1"
        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1204/3320/products/46801850054_ea0cb77ced_o_800x800.jpg?v=1554836834"
      />
      <img
        class="image-2"
        src="https://www.1800flowers.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/160080m-274x300.jpg"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
 #flower-background-1 {
    background-image: url("https://www.fiftyflowers.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/iStock-659171982-1170x449.jpg");
    height: 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .img-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  #welcome {
    font-family: "Great Vibes", cursive;
    font-size: 50px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 150px;
    background-color: indigo;
  }

  .image-1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 114px;
    border: 2px solid red;
  }

  .image-2 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
```

Your problems will be solved.
Wish this helps you.

Comment: Had to downvote. Next time, along with telling them what they did wrong, give descriptive ways to help them fix it.